# MSG 2714 There is an object already named

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE PROC PS_LOGIN(
    @ID NVARCHAR(50), 
    @PSW NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Table_Users WHERE ID=@ID AND PSW=@PSW
END
```

Comment: Please always format your codes. Also provide completer error message in the body of the question (not the subject)

Comment: `drop procedure ps_login` or `alter procedure ps_login`.

Comment: ERROR IN HERE ID=@ID AND PSW=@PSW

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
IF OBJECT_ID('PS_LOGIN' , 'P') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP PROC PS_LOGIN 
GO


CREATE PROC PS_LOGIN(
    @ID NVARCHAR(50), 
    @PSW NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Table_Users WHERE ID=@ID AND PSW=@PSW
END
GO
```